# Python - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I was trying to make a wikipedia crawler that gets the "See also" links text and then enters the urls that  tags link to. However, "See also" part of the article (which is an unorganized list) doesn't have any class or id, so i get it with a method "find_next_sibling". Next, it goes through every linked Wikipedia page there, and does the same thing. This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def wikipediaCrawler(page, maxPages):

    pageNumber = 1
    while pageNumber < maxPages:
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + page
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        print(sourceCode)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
        ul = soup.find("h2", text="See also").find_next_sibling("ul")
        for li in ul.findAll("li"):
            print(li.get_text())
        for link in ul.findAll('a'):
            page = str(link.get('href'))
            print(page)
        pageNumber += 1


wikipediaCrawler("/wiki/Online_chat", 3)
```

It prints the first page normally.
The problem is that whenever it tries to switch the page I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shaman/PycharmProjects/WebCrawler/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    wikipediaCrawler("/wiki/Online_chat", 3)
  File "C:/Users/Shaman/PycharmProjects/WebCrawler/main.py", line 14, in wikipediaCrawler
    ul = soup.find("h2", text="See also").find_next_sibling("ul")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'
```

I print the requests function and it says "Response<200>" so it doesn't seem like a permission issue. I honestly have no clue why it happens. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Edit: I know that the Wikipedia articles that it searches all contain  tag with text "See also". In this case it earched "Voice_chat" article and didn't find anything despite it being there.

Comment: `soup.find("h2", text="See also")``, isn't finding anything.

Comment: for what you need maxPages ?

Comment: I know by source code that on every page h2 with a text "See also" exists and the next sibling with tag ul exists too

Comment: @zimdero It was to stop the crawler after browsing certain amount of Wikipedia articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the `<ul>` after the `h2` tag that starts the "See also" section.

One way to find that `h2` is to use [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to find the right tag, then grab the parent element (the `h2`), and then get the next sibling from there:

```
def wikipediaCrawler(page, maxPages):

    #...

    soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")

    see_also = soup.select("h2 > #See_also")[0]
    ul = see_also.parent.find_next_sibling("ul")

    for link in ul.findAll('a'):
        page = str(link.get('href'))
        print(page)

wikipediaCrawler("/wiki/Online_chat", 3)
```

Output:

```
/wiki/Chat_room
/wiki/Collaborative_software
/wiki/Instant_messaging
/wiki/Internet_forum
/wiki/List_of_virtual_communities_with_more_than_100_million_active_users
/wiki/Online_dating_service
/wiki/Real-time_text
/wiki/Videotelephony
/wiki/Voice_chat
/wiki/Comparison_of_VoIP_software
/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_game
/wiki/Online_game
/wiki/Video_game_culture
```

Answer (score -1):

The piece of code `soup.find("h2", text="See also")` sometime just can not find the element and then return `None`.

Quick fix is to pass the error:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def wikipediaCrawler(page, maxPages):
    pageNumber = 1
    while pageNumber < maxPages:
        try:
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + page
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        print(sourceCode)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
        ul = soup.find("h2", text="See also").find_next_sibling("ul")
        for li in ul.findAll("li"):
            print('li: ', pageNumber, li.get_text())
        for link in ul.findAll('a'):
            page = str(link.get('href'))
            print('a:', pageNumber, page)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        print soup.find("h2", text="See also")

    pageNumber += 1

wikipediaCrawler("/wiki/Online_chat", 3)
```

I added a small change in printing to debug easier.

Comment: It prints: <Response [200]>
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'
None    It seems it gets to the webpage but then it can't find the h2, no matter if it exists or not